# Mixed content: insecure font URL showing as 'https:' only

Tags: https, mixed-content

Please see image below. These errors are only happening on Chrome. It seems to download a font but URL is only 'https:'

I have searched all of my source codes and there is NO single request to any font or css with only has 'https:' URL. I have everything in absolute URL.

[Font url only showing as 'https:'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXmzk.png)

[Network traffic showing requests to download fonts with 'https:' URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4YCw.png)

Comment: Are you using a cloud hosting such as a2hosting?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are using Cloudflare and you may want to check out this link [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04#prerequisites)

Comment: Identified the problem already. modernizr.js injects style block with some @font-face definition with url specfied as url:('https://')